# Running python as root using new pyenv and venv

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cron, python-venv, pyenv

> - Python applications currently are being run as root.
> - These applications are in a cron job.
> - They are called using /usr/bin/python3 app1.py

I want to setup a new venv for a new application using a specific python version.

> Note: *All under root*.
>
> - I could use pyenv to setup python3 version.
> - I could use venv to setup packages.

How does one setup cron job to run the application?
/my/path/myapp.py

I have never run non-interactively.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a cron file /etc/cron.d/your_cron in which you either set HOME variable (defining the working directory) or run cd /my/path. Then you simply provide the commands for pyenv and venv. The file should then look something like this:

```html
HOME=/my/app
1 0 * * * pyenv local <version> && python3 -m venv <virtual env> && python3 app.py
```

or

```html
1 0 * * * cd /my/path && pyenv local <version> && python3 -m venv <virtual env> && python3 app.py
```